# logout method doesnt delete token from db

Tags: php, pdo, jwt, sql-delete, logout

I've created logout algoritm which have 3 parts.

1. First layer is endpoint which I'm calling from postman and will be calling from front-end.
2. Second is method in User class which actually do all the stuff.
3. Third is Token class which I'm using in User class to check if token is still same and to decode it in order to gather user ID which is encoded in token.

Code of my endpoint is:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // LOGOUT DOESN't WORK and it still dont give me any errors

    // required headers
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    // include needed files
    include_once '../config/database.php';
    include_once '../classes/user.php';
    include_once '../classes/token.php';

    // instantiate database and product object
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    // initialize object
    $user = new user($db);
    $token = new token($db);

    $cleanToken = '';

    if(function_exists('apache_request_headers'))
    {
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        $cleanToken = $token->cutToken($headers);
    }
    else
    {
        http_response_code(500);
        die();
    }

    if(isset($cleanToken) && !empty($cleanToken))
    {
        if($user->logout($cleanToken))
        {
            http_response_code(200);
        }
        else
        {
            http_response_code(401);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        http_response_code(400);
    }
```

What is funny that when I call it from postman it return status of 200 so it seems like everything is working but it doesn't.

Now the code of logout function in User class is:

```
public function logout($receivedToken)
{
    include '../config/database.php';
    include '../classes/token.php';

    // instantiate database
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $token = new token($db);
    if($token->checkToken($receivedToken))
    {
        $userId = $token->getUserId($receivedToken);
        $query = "
            DELETE
              token
            FROM  
              " . $this->table_name . "
            WHERE
              id = ?
        ";

        try
        {
            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            //bind values from user
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $userId);

            $return = $stmt->execute();

            if($return === true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it is returning true because like I said I got 200 in postman but it doesn't delete token from DB. Why? It doesn't print out any additional error info or anything.

Just let me know if you need any additional informations or code.

**EDIT**

- I change code of endpoint I added 3 lines which should set show error to true.
- I change code of logout function I added try..catch in order to show some errors.

Still don't have any error after doing call via postman:

[image: img]

Comment: why are you using `$this->conn` when you've declared the connection as `$db = $database->getConnection();`? is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: use error reporting for the php and error handling on the pdo.

Comment: this is my db conf file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5bd2589d07dd33ae755f55649e532477

Comment: Funk Forty Niner how exacly should pdo handling look like?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - see if anything comes of those.

Comment: I added `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of my endpoint but it didn't change anything, I mean I still don't get any error in postman.

Comment: Why somebody downvoted this question? If I didn't provide some details please just let me know.

Comment: There is TOO MUCH details. Basically you are asking "debug this wall of code for me". Is your problem related to a database? or to JWT? Or SQL? Or you want someone to tell you what your question is?

Comment: I think there is problem with database connection somewhere. If I knew what exactly the problem is I would fix it. Anyway I think this is problem with db. I will edit question within an hour.

Comment: @Your Common Sense It was related to SQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution here is exceedingly simple and I'm very surprised that anyone couldn't help me with it and I'm upset at myself that I spent decidedly too much time at this.

So I wanted to delete token from token column but I used bad sql operation for that. `DELETE` is for deleting entire record not only one value. I should have used `UPDATE` instead.